# performing MockMvc : getting error while performing mockMvc on post api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockmvc

getting error while performing mockMvc on post api.
because in this post call my service layer checks the customer is exist or not.
so it is giving me customer not found error.
how can i mock customer here?

```
        final String PAYMENT_METHOD = "/customer/"+customerId+"/paymentMethod";
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(PAYMENT_METHOD).content(JsonUtils.toJson(paymentMethodDto))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept((MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(request).andExpect(status().isCreated()).andReturn();
        Assert.assertEquals(result.getResponse().getStatus(), HttpStatus.CREATED.value());
        ResponseEntity<PaymentMethodRes> responseEntity = paymentMethodController.addPaymentMethod(customerId, paymentMethodDto);
        assertNotNull(responseEntity);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work

```
Mockito.when(customerService.findCustumerbyId(customerId).thenReturn(new Customer());`
```